# Unable to include file in fetch() POST request

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

For some reason, I can't get file transfers to work via [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch). My code is really simple:

```
export function updateProfilePicture(apiKey, userID, picture) {
  let data = new FormData();
  data.append('picture', picture);
  return fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/${ROOT}/update_profile_picture/${userID}`,{
    headers: {'Authorization': `Token token=${apiKey}`},
    method: 'POST',
    data: data
  }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

However, the resulting request does not seem to include any file whatsoever. Am I missing something? In the above example, picture is instance an of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two reasons:

1. `data` field in [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is called `body`. Use this instead of `data` property.
2. (optional) You need to add another header: `'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'`

Read more about Fetch API:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
- [Fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: Thanks! Using body instead of data worked. Completely misread the API there.